# How do we fine-tune Llama 2 model for Custom Intent Classification?

Tags: machine-learning, training-data, text-classification, fine-tuning

How do we fine-tune Llama 2 model for text classification? Additionally, what should the training data be like for Custom Intent Classification?

I aim to fine-tune the llama2 model to detect and recognize intents/classifications in real time from user input.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.